# How to use setAnimationStartDate in the UIView？

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, uiview

How to use setAnimationStartDate？
The following code does not work.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0]; 
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];
[UIView setAnimationStartDate:date];

CGPoint point = _imageView.center;
point.y += 150;
[_imageView setCenter:point];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: According to the docs -- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationStartDate: -- "use of this method [`setAnimationStartDate:`] is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later". But if you must use it, try replacing `[UIView setAnimationStartDate:date];` with `[UIView setAnimationStartDate: CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() + 3];` so it's more in line with the `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` default value.

Comment: Thank you！If it is not recommended, So don't use.

Answer (score 1):

You could use block-based animations. They are much cleaner and can do exactly what you need. One method to look at is `+[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations: completion:]`. The `delay` parameter would be useful in your situation. Here is an example.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 
                      delay:3 
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn 
                  animations: ^{
                                     CGPoint point = _imageView.center;
                                     point.y += 150;
                                     [_imageView setCenter:point];
                               } 
                  completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                                     NSLog(@"Animation Complete");
                               }];
```

You may have to mess around with the `delay` to mimic your `NSDate` setup.

Comment: I know this. Thank you!