# Why does "+ (void)setAnimationStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate;" not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uiviewanimation

I am study about **`UIView Animation`**, I found when I use "`+ (void)setAnimationStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate`;" between the *`beginAnimations:context`:* and *`commitAnimations`* methods, it does not work

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"demo" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0f];
[UIView setAnimationStartDate:[NSDate date]];
// do something
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Because the method default is now (`NSDate` date), I even try "`[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]`", it does not work, too.

If I don't use the method, it works as usual. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setAnimationStartDate` that means you are providing start time to this animation. so, it will not start before that time is coming.

As [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationStartDate:) states,

> Call this method between the beginAnimations:context: and commitAnimations methods to specify the start time for that set of animations. And call this method prior to changing the animatable properties of your views. (Do not call this method in conjunction with a block-based animation.) If you do not call this method, the start time is set to the value returned by the CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent function, which begins the animations as soon as possible.

Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

Refer documentation for more details.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Hello. I try to use '[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]'. But, After I wait 5 seconds, it does not work. I search int the internet,  someone say use '[UIView setAnimationStartDate: CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() + 5];', it can not compiled now.

Comment: Yes, because you are passing ` CFAbsoluteTime` kind of parameter instead of `NSDate` type!

Comment: Now tell me what you want to do exactly ? Do you want to animate the view ? or do you want to animate at particular predefined time?

Comment: Thank you. I am learning about `UIView`, I'm just want to know every method.I just don't understand why do not work. Maybe Apple has changes this method.

Comment: Yes,I try to use `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()+3]`, it still does not work

Comment: Your post is related to animation on `UIView` not about `UIView`. So what you want to know or learn? Be specific

Comment: I am learning animation in `UIView`,I am trying to each method about animation.But I found the method does not work as it is described in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761892/how-to-use-setanimationstartdate-in-the-uiview). I think that you just need to refactor your code with method `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` of class `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setAnimationDelay:` for same functionality. It works!!

```
[UIView setAnimationDelay:5];
```

[image]
See more detail on [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html). Not sure why `setAnimationStartDate:` doesn't work, It should have worked as this is mentioned in above doc.

Comment: Thank you. I am learning about `UIView`, I'm just want to know every method.I just don't understand why do not work. Maybe Apple has changes this method.I will use other methods instead.